# Problems with Panel custom color

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, colors, panel

I verify the structure of code css in bootstrap.css file of panel-primary structure and I want to create a custom color. Then, I create a separate css and make:

```
.panel-custom {
  border-color: #7e1416;
}
.panel-custom > .panel-heading {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #7e1416;
  border-color: #7e1416;
}
.panel-custom > .panel-heading + .panel-collapse > .panel-body {
  border-top-color: #7e1416;
}
.panel-custom > .panel-heading .badge {
  color: #7e1416;
  background-color: #7e1416;
}
.panel-custom > .panel-footer + .panel-collapse > .panel-body {
  border-bottom-color: #7e1416;
}
```

The problem is, I can't modify the color again. If a change the color, my object keep the first color configuration. And more, if I comment the code, the objects  keep style of panel-custom!

Why it's happenning?

Answer (score 0):

I think is a problem with browser cache.
I execute Ctrl+F5 in browser and the changes have apllied.

Thanks!